# Installing telepresence with a pod security policy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, telepresence, podsecuritypolicy

I'm trying to install telepresence into a EKS cluster that has PodSecurityPolicy's. I've gotten the traffic manager installed by running helm on the traffic manager chart:

```bash
helm install traffic-manager -n ambassador datawire/telepresence --create-namespace
```

After that I modify the `traffic-manager-ambassador` clusterRole to use one of the cluster PodSecurityPolicy's. Installation of the traffic manager eventually succeeds after I do this. However the installation of the `uninstall-agent` job fails:

```
Error creating: pods "uninstall-agents-" is forbidden: PodSecurityPolicy: unable to admit pod: []
```

My question is - what role or clusterRole do I have to modify to allow helm to uninstall telepresence? Or how do I figure out what service account is being used to try and install the pod so I can give it access to a pod security policy?

Answer (score 0):

I made some fixes at https://github.com/ddl-pjohnson/telepresence/pull/1/files to make it easier to add additional rules and to run the helm hook as the correct user.